# UIDocument Opening to populate TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uidocument

I am using a DocumentBrowserViewController in Swift to present documents to a ViewController.  In the ViewController I have a tableView to present some of the data in the document.  When the ViewController is presented, it wants to initialize the tableView first.  Settings of the tableView (ex:  func TableView: nbrOfRowsInSection) are set by data in the document.  Since the document is not read yet it fails.

I have the document.open in the ViewWillAppear which I was thinking would execute first.

Is there a way to change this ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `viewWillAppear` does not execute first, the first one is `viewDidLoad`. Depending on how you are initialising your ViewController, it can be `awakeFromNib` as well.

But it still should not fail, just do something similar to this:

```
var dataFromDocument: SomeData {
    didSet {
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

final public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataFromDocument.size
}
```

You can then read the data and set `dataFromDocument` when the reading of the document is finished.

Comment: Thank you.  Moving to viewDidLoad did not work for some reason.  However the following does the trick:

return dataFromDocument == nil ? 1 : (dataFromDocument?.steps.count)!

Comment: It would have been way more helpful if you would have posted your code. Please do, that way one can offer better help.